# error connecting to b1ws, Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: web-services, wsdl, sapb1

I'm just starting out with SAP B1WS, here is a simple console application:

```
 Sub Main()
    Dim login = New LoginService
    Dim SessionId = login.Login("99.99.99.99", "aa", LoginDatabaseType.dst_MSSQL2005, True, "MyUser", "MyPass", LoginLanguage.ln_English, True, "99.99.99.99:30010")
End Sub
```

Running this gives the following error:

> {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:80"}

I made some generic research about `wsdl`/`asmx` and couldn't find anything relevant.

Firewalls are turned off by me and by the server, for purpose of this test.

I tried running a test here http://wsdlbrowser.com/ and all i get is a "Not Found" error. no additional info.

here's the request I'm sending to http://99.99.99.99/B1WS/WebReferences/LoginService.wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="LoginService">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:Login>
  <ns1:DatabaseServer>a</ns1:DatabaseServer>
  <ns1:DatabaseName>a</ns1:DatabaseName>
  <ns1:DatabaseType>a</ns1:DatabaseType>
  <ns1:CompanyUsername>a</ns1:CompanyUsername>
  <ns1:CompanyPassword>a</ns1:CompanyPassword>
  <ns1:Language>a</ns1:Language>
  <ns1:LicenseServer>a</ns1:LicenseServer>
</ns1:Login>
```

I'm sending dummy data, since I don't think it's even hitting the server. If it was hitting the server, I believe i would get a more specific error. such as invalid password etc.

what might the problem be?

TIA

Comment: any ideas, anybody?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right. It's not hitting the correct server. Firstly configure B1WS folder in IIS and then try executing your code with proper login credentials.

Comment: hi. thanks for answering, unfortuanetly the project went down due to this connection issue. thanks anyways!